# Curl: how data is interpreted by Java InputStream, if I sent it using curl --data-binary?

Tags: java, http, curl, post, server

I have a server, written on Java, which is currently running on a

> http://localhost:8080

Source code is hidden from me, but I know that all endpoints are handled by Java HttpExchange class, for example endpoint:

> http://localhost:8080/generate/init

will be handled like that:

```
public void init(HttpExchange httpex) throws IOException {
...
}
```

The next thing I know is that incoming POST requests are handled like that:

```
byte post_data = (byte) httpex.getRequestBody().read();
```

My question is, that when I do from a command-line:

```
echo -e '\x03' | curl -X POST -i --data-binary @- http://localhost:8080/generate/init
```

What will be the value of post_data?
As I understand curl will send '\x03' exactly as it is:

> \x03

And Java HttpExchange method getRequestBody() will return InputStream of it, where read() will translate that InputStream into int. As much as I know, Java doesn't interpret HEX as '\x03', instead it uses Unicode '\u0003'. Therefore I'm afraid of sending wrong data into my server.

> If I'm wrong about curl --data-binary, please correct me! I just wish
> to be sure, that I pass number "3" by POST request and server
> interprets it as number 3, but in bytes ((byte) 3)

Comment: I would think if Curl is telling the sever that it's sending data-binary, the Java side will just read raw bytes. Unicode won't come into it

Comment: `echo -e '\x03'` does not emit the four characters ‘backslash x zero three.’  It sends one byte, which happens to be one character whose ASCII code is 03 (the control code character named “ETX”).  Java doesn’t interpret it as anything else.  However, Java debuggers may choose to *show* that character as `\u0003`, since it’s a non-printing character on all non-Windows systems.

Comment: @VGR so '\x03' is not interpreted as number 3 on Java side? Well, then should I use '\x33' instead ? (ASCII: 3).

Comment: That depends on what the Java side is doing.  `\x03` is interpreted as the byte value 3, and the code may well choose to promote it to the integer value 3.  If you want the Java side to receive the ASCII digit instead, `\x33` would be correct, but without seeing more of that code, or at least its documentation, I can’t say which value you should send.

Comment: @VGR, yep finally, with your explanation I did a bit of research and it turned out, that indeed, at Java side that \x03 is interpreted as int 3 not ascii char ETX. So program is doing everything correctly! Thank you for your hints!